# cocoa - why the application support directory changes?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I have an ad-hoc provisioning of my app.
Every time i install a new version of the application using the ad-hoc provisioning, the application support directory is different.

I use the following code:

```
NSArray* path = NSSearchPathForDriectoriesInDomains(NSApllicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* appSupportDir = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [path objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Why?

Comment: I suppose that's because the system performs an UUID generation on every install. BTW, shouldn't `NSString* appSupportDir = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [path objectAtIndex:0]];` be simply `NSString* appSupportDir = path objectAtIndex:0];` or maximum `retain` it?

Comment: But this id suppose to be the application ID. It should never change

Comment: What is the actual output you get? The install directory is *not* the application ID.